Adding cmd_vel and Odom to Tracked Controller
I'm wanting to use the libSimpleTrackedVehiclePlugin.so library and control it using ros2. I would like to publish to a cmd_vel topic to move the robot. I would also like to add odometry into the plugin (or any other way) so I can see the exact location but also add some sensor noise to simulate a real world example.
Has anyone got any suggestions as to how to do this?
